# Pointer to struct containing structs

Tags: c, pointers, thread-safety

I am writing a multithreaded application and would like to pass around pointers to a struct.

Do the structs in the struct need to be malloced or if the outer struct is malloced will it prevent the internal structs from being deleted or lost when passing around the pointer?

Struct I am asking about is

```
struct thread_data
{
    position starttile;
    position destinationtile;
    char *message;
};
```

where position is a struct itself that contains no pointers

Comment: Are the inner structs value members, or pointer members?

Comment: Then please see my answer. There is only one block of memory being allocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the struct contains child structs, then it is generally all one block of memory. And so there would be no separate allocation.

If the struct instead contains pointers to structs, then my previous comment would not apply. In this case, it kind of depends on what you are doing.

Had you considered posting a tiny bit of code so people would have a clue what you had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably find it easier to manage memory if you do

```
struct X {
   struct Y data;
};
struct X* var = malloc(sizeof(struct X));
```

instead of

```
struct X {
   struct Y* pData;
};
struct X* var = malloc(sizeof(struct X));
var->pData = malloc(sizeof(struct Y));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your outer `struct` contains actual structures, there's no need to allocate them separately.
If your outer `struct` contains pointers to structures, then they'll need to be allocated somewhere.

It is easier if your outer structure contains actual structures.  Even so, with pointers, simply make sure that you never make the pointer to the outer structure available to other threads until the inner structures are fully allocated - which avoids threading issues on allocation.  Deallocation will require suitable care to ensure exclusive access.